# Editing a plist within Xcode

Tags: iphone, uitableview, plist

I would like to edit a plist from Xcode which I will use to fill the table view.

The thing is I have an array of images, and the user can add one of these images to a favorites list.

This needs to be written to the plist. So I need the index number of the image and the name they choose to save it with. How can I write to a plist?

Then when they view favorites and they select an item in the table, that needs to load and display the appropriate image.

I was thinking of writing the name they choose with the number of the index appended with for e.g. "index_titleSaved" and then when reading from the plist I could just grab the number before the first _. and then show it.

Is this a good way or could it be done more efficiently?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an NSDictionary's `writeToFile` method, or, if you want an array (or an array of dictionarys), use NSArray's `writeToFile` method.

Answer (score 0):

According to your second question, I think your app crash because Array use a numeric key and can't use NSString as key. If you need a key->value structure you have to use NSDictionary

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to use is

```
NSDictionary* plistArray = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
```